# How to "rotate" the items in an array while conceptualizing it as a square shape?

Tags: c#, arrays, rotation, coordinate-transformation

I’m trying to track the positions of cubelets in a Rubik’s cube. Currently I have it select a cubelet and an axis to rotate on which then retrieves the other cubelets in the plane of rotation and stores them in a List. Im having trouble coming up with a formula that takes the index and returns the index of where it would be after the rotation is done.

I made formulas that works for rotating a face plane, but because I cull the inter cubelets of the Rubik’s cube, I can't figure out a way to modify them to account for the missing cubelets in the inner planes.

The first formula is for counter-clockwise rotation and the second for clockwise rotation, where Size is the dimension of the cube, SizeSq is the dimension^2, and index is the index of the cubelet to be rotated in the List.

return (Size - 1) + (Size * (index % Size)) - Mathf.FloorToInt(index / Size);
return (SizeSq - 1) - ((Size - 1) + (Size * (index % Size)) - Mathf.FloorToInt(index / Size));

The images show what I trying to accomplish with before and after a counter-clockwise rotation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK14A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KCco.png)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just apply transformation matrix to centered coordinates of each component. Ie, source index in array -> 3d vector -> centered 3d vector -> transformation -> centered 3d vector -> 3d vector -> target index in array. You can rotate as many times as you want this way. And I doubt you will be doing billions of rotations so there is no need to optimize it.